# how to set apostrophe in TextView programming

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

TextView.setText(String with ') , i wanna set a text to the text view but this text keep coming uncompleted in case it has Space or  apostrophe 
i have tried to use

```
String SomeString="MacDonald's";
```

or

```
 SomeString="Fast Food";
```

and i tried the following

```
 HTML.Fromhtml(SomeString).tostring()
```

and

```
 SomeString.replace("'","\\\'")
```

but with no good result
the Result always

```
MacDon 
Fast
```

any good ideas ?!

Comment: you mean to say textview with text wihtout spaces

Comment: plz show us how the String `someString` looks like and what you expect to get as result

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your apostrophe is `'` and not special one like `‘`

Answer (score 1):

From android developer documentation

you can set apostrophe from XML

> Single quote (')
>
> Any of the following:
>
> ```
> 1. &apos; 
> 2. \'
> 3. Enclose the entire string in double quotes ("This'll work", for example)
> ```

Sample

```
1. <string name="travelers_details">Traveler&apos;s Information</string>

2. <string name="travelers_details">Traveler\'s Information</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apastrophe cannot be directly displayed. Instead of directly placing Apastrophe use the below when you encounter the apastrophe as below:

```
  if (YourString.contains("'")) {
      YourString= YourString.replaceAll("'", "\'");
    }
```

This will help you

Comment: did not work + many words retrieved from the data base comes correct till the part they should be set to the Textview and the TextView.getText() return the correct value but it displayed uncompleted in the interface

Answer (score 0):

I believe, calling `yourTextView.setText("MacDonald's");` will simply set **MacDonald's** inside your `TextView`. You don't need anything fancy to get it printed.

Comment: i set the data from cursor values in the adapter , and when i even try to hard code the value still the same error ,, the word come back uncompleted

Comment: can you first try to log the values from cursor? I think its not the problem with TextView. Perhaps the values you are getting from cursor is in parts

Comment: No i debugged and every thing is working fine even after set the value in the text i watch TextView.getText(); and it return for me the correct value that saved in the database but the problem comes on the interface level ?!